# finding the first and last entry with a certain value in a row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel sheet containing multiple cells with a string `foo` in the first row. I want to find the first and last column in which the string is written. I have tried the following

```
Dim first_col As Integer
Dim last_col As Integer
Dim col As Integer
Dim found As Range
Dim ws_MLB as Worksheet
Dim foo as String

set ws_MLB = ThisWorkbook.Sheet(1)

Set found = ws_MLB.Rows(1).Find(foo)
If Not found Is Nothing Then
    col = found.Column
    first_col = col
    last_col = col
    Do
        found = ws_MLB.Rows(1).FindNext(found)
        col = found.Column

        If col < first_col Then
            first_col = col
            MsgBox ("This should not happen")
        ElseIf col > last_col Then
            last_col = col
        End If
    Loop While Not found Is Nothing And col <> first_col
Else
    MsgBox ("not found")
End If
```

But this way I only get the the first value for both first_col and last_col. When I search for the string with the integrated excel search I find multiple instances. So the string is there. Have I done a mistake or is there a better way to do this?

edit forgot to mention that I also tried to change the search direction, but I still got the first entry.

Comment: .find is wonderful and all that, but wouldn't it be easier to just use a for next loop?  Start at the front, and look in each cell until you find foo, then start at the end, and work backwards (for x = lastcell to 1 step -1), until you find the last one.

Comment: As far as I figuered find is a lot faster then iterating. http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/. In this case it might be faster but I wanted to get used to findnext, but it just didn't work.

Comment: Yes, no doubt that find is faster than for/next, but really, how wide can it be?  I have been trying to use find more lately as well, though so far, only for vertical lists.  You may need to invoke more of the options each time.  This is a typical way I invoke find... Set FindCell = shSrc.Range("A1", shSrc.Cells(shBottom, "A")).Find(What:=StrValue, after:=shc.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
        
 If FindCell Is Nothing Then
'do one thing            
Else
'do another
end if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this a lot easier by using the `SearchDirection` Parameter in `.Find` by using `xlNext` you search Left to Right then `xlPrevious` searches Right to Left.

```
Sub FindFL()

    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim fColumn As Long, lColumn As Long

    Set wbk = ThisWorkbook 'Change this to your workbook
    Set ws = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change this to your worksheet

    With ws
        'Find first column that foo shows up
        fColumn = .Cells.Find(What:="foo", _
            After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False).Column
        'Find last column that foo shows up
        lColumn = .Cells.Find(What:="foo", _
            After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            MatchCase:=False).Column

        Debug.Print "First Column is " & fColumn; vbNewLine _
        ; "Last Column is " & lColumn
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: yeah forgot to say that I tried the direction thing. Quite similar to this still I got the first entry.

Comment: @KamiKaze Have you tried the above code? It worked for me when I tested it.

Answer (score -1):

I would do that like this:

```
Public Sub foo()
  Dim nCol As Integer
  Dim nFirst As Integer
  Dim nLast As Integer

  With ActiveSheet
    nCol = 1
    Do Until .Cells(1, nCol) = ""
      If .Cells(1, nCol) = "foo" Then
        If nFirst = 0 Then
          nFirst = nCol
        Else
          nLast = nCol
        End If
      End If
      nCol = nCol + 1
    Loop
  End With

  MsgBox "First: " & nFirst & vbCr & "Last: " & nLast
End Sub
```

Comment: Well this is the brute force approach I tried to avoid. Find is used that you don't have to do it that way.